# Is it possible to invoke my listview element for another ui element?

Tags: c#

im very new to c# and im messing around with a windows form project, but i can't invoke my UI thread from my user control.
I am trying to call a method to update a listview, by clearing the listview and putting in the objects from my list (refresh), the method works when i click it in the same UI as the listview, but ive made an option to edit an item from the listview and it pops up in a new form.

This leads to the problem of trying to invoke the old ui. I think im doing it wrong! :D

I've spend all morning searching for answers here, with no luck. I've added var handle = this.Handle; to InitializeComponent (because it threw exceptions about having no handle) and i found this as a solution, it did remove the exception, however it did not make the listview refresh.

Calling my form to edit:

```cs
new Thread (() => r.ShowDialog() ).Start();
```

The actiont that happens when u save edit:

```cs
if (vareUC.IsHandleCreated) //check if handle is created in vareUC(contains the listview and fyldListe method, which refreshes the list)
{
     if (vareUC.InvokeRequired)
     {
          vareUC.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { vareUC.fyldListe(); }));
     }
      else
     {
          vareUC.Invoke(new Action(() => { vareUC.fyldListe(); }));
     }
}
else
{
     // in this case InvokeRequired might lie - you need to make sure that this never happens! 
     throw new Exception("Somehow Handle has not yet been created on the UI thread!");
}
```

The method to refresh the list:

```cs
public async void fyldListe()
{
     listView1.Clear();

     vareListe.Clear();
     DBVare db = new DBVare();
     await db.GetVare(vareListe);
     listView1.View = View.Details;
     listView1.Columns.Add("Nr", 50);
     listView1.Columns.Add("Navn",250);
     listView1.Columns.Add("Beskrivelse",400);
     listView1.Columns.Add("Lager",100);
     listView1.Columns.Add("Indkøbspris",100);
     listView1.Columns.Add("Salgspris",100);
     listView1.Columns.Add("Udgået",50);
     listView1.FullRowSelect = true;



     var udg = "";

     var listarray = vareListe.ToArray();
     foreach (var c in listarray)
     {
          udg = "";
          if (c.udgået.ToString() == "1")
          udg = "Udgået";

          listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] 
          { 
                 c.vareNr.ToString(),
                 c.vareNavn,
                 c.vareBeskrivelse, 
                 c.lagerBeholdning.ToString(), 
                 c.indkøbsPris.ToString(),
                 c.salgsPris.ToString(),
                 udg 
           }));
     }
}
```

This code runs, and it doesnt produce any runtime errors nor does it actually do what i want it to(refresh the listview). Please help a new c# developer out! :)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but however as I understood, you want to access a list from another form. if the other form runs in the same thread then you don't need this and just passing your list view as the other form property would give access to it. if the other form runs on another thread(?) then you need to explain more I think.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani i updated my question i hope this is info enough to maybe see what i'm trying - again sorry for bad explanation im very new at programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you should only invoke when invoke is requied so the code should be like this:

```
if(vareUC != null)
{
     if (vareUC.InvokeRequired)
     {
        vareUC.Invoke(new Action(() => { vareUC.fyldListe(); }));

     }
     else
     {
         vareUC.fyldListe(); // no invoke required so it is on the same thread 
     }
}
```

Comment: Now i got a  nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object on testing if(vareUC.IsHandleCreated)

Comment: well if you get nullreferenceexception, obviously when you are getting there `vareUC` is null so you should check it like `if(vareUC != null) { your code here }`

Comment: Yea i set it properly now, no exception and still doesnt refresh my listview :(

Comment: well you should check why when you get there it its null, surely you should have instanciated (or assigned) it before you get there.

Comment: yes i have just fixed that before posting last time :)